# Fiddler not capturing local traffic from webClient on LINQPad

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

Team,

I have the following simple WebClient call from LINQPad. How ever I try Fiddler just refuses to capture. 
I am just running out of ways. Instead of 127.0.0.1, I have tried localhost, localhost.(with dot), localhost.fiddler, and my machine name. Fiddler is just not interested to capture this at all. Any one has any ideas.

```
void Main()
{
    CookieWebClient client = new CookieWebClient() 
    {    
        Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888)    // Fiddler 
    };             
    Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString(url)); // Cookie is created here 
    Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString(url)); //  In this request, the cookie gets sent back to the web API
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class CookieWebClient : WebClient 
{    
    private CookieContainer jar = new CookieContainer(); 
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)    
    {        
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);                     
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;        
        if (webRequest != null)            
            webRequest.CookieContainer = jar;                     
        return request;    
    } 
}
string url = "http://localhost:21531/api/employees/12345";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't explained *what actually happens* when you try.

The .NET Framework bypasses the proxy for any HTTP/HTTPS request to `localhost`, so you **must** use `localhost.fiddler` as the host in your `string url`. When you do so, there are two possibilities:

1. The request succeeds, which means that Fiddler captures the traffic
2. The request fails, which means that your client isn't properly configured to proxy its requests.

Comment: Hi Eric, Your suggestion to change string URL did the trick. The following finally worked. string url = "http://localhost.fiddler:21531/api/employees/12345"; For over an hour I was only manipulating Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888); with different combinations I mentioned. Thank You so much.

Comment: I'm using LinqPad with a HttpClient. I have: `var webAddr = "http://localhost.fiddler:53733/";` but Fiddler still sees nothing.

Comment: @MKenyonII - See the answer above. If the request is failing, it means your proxy is not properly configured.